# Kotlin Error : Dagger does not support injection into private fields private boolean isAppNull;

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I am getting this error on a field that is not private. I am trying to inject a boolean field in my MainActivity. This is how I defined my BaseApplication.

```
class BaseApplication : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication>? {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
    }

}
```

This is my AppComponent code :

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityBuildersModule::class,
        AppModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<BaseApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application) : Builder

        fun build() : AppComponent
    }
}
```

This is my ActivityBuildersModule :

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeMainActivity() : MainActivity
}
```

This is my AppModule

```
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesAppCheck(application: Application) : Boolean = application == null

}
```

This is where I declared isAppNull

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {


    @Inject
    var isAppNull : Boolean

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val tf = FontCache.get("fonts/" + "GlacialIndifference-Regular.otf", this)
        TypeFaceUtil.overrideFont(this, "SERIF", tf!!)

        val binding: ActivityMainBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        binding.viewmodel = viewModel

    }
}
```

I cannot understand how to invoke the Boolean field in my MainActivity class. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGSvQi6N-ok&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8AOAspC3DHoBNZIBHbIOsC&index=8)

Comment: Show the code for where the `isAppNull` is implemented and being injected

Comment: I think dagger does not care about the names but only cares about the return types. so It should get the value from providesAppCheck() method defined in AppModule.

Comment: Don't use private while injecting the isAppNull

Comment: Ok I have edited and added the MainActivity class where I declared the isAppNull field

Comment: No, this is different. I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGSvQi6N-ok&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8AOAspC3DHoBNZIBHbIOsC&index=8